# Craft Commerce: Detecting & Styling Flash Messages?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I'm styling my flash messages in Craft Commerce - I added if statements to detect the type of flash message. I noticed however that the message no longer displays but the styling does get picked up. Any ideas what I might need to do here?

```
{% if craft.session.getFlash('notice') %}
    <div data-alert class="alert-box info radius">
      {{ craft.session.getFlash('notice') }}
      <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
    </div>
{% endif %}

{% if craft.session.getFlash('error') %}
    <div data-alert class="alert-box alert radius">
      {{ craft.session.getFlash('error') }}
      <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Getting a flash message also deletes it, so you should set it to a variable first, otherwise, when you try to access it a second time, it will be empty.

So you need to do something like this:

```
{% set flashNotice = craft.session.getFlash('notice') %}
{% if flashNotice %}
    <div data-alert class="alert-box info radius">
      {{ flashNotice }}
      <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
    </div>
{% endif %}

{% set flashError = craft.session.getFlash('error') %}
{% if flashError %}
    <div data-alert class="alert-box alert radius">
      {{ flashError }}
      <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`hasFlash()`](https://craftcms.com/classreference/variables/UserSessionVariable#hasFlash-detail) instead, or pass `false` as a third argument, otherwise the flash message is discarded after the first time it is accessed.

```
{% if craft.session.getFlash('notice', null, false) %}
    <div data-alert class="alert-box info radius">
      {{ craft.session.getFlash('notice') }}
      <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

or

```
{% if craft.session.hasFlash('error') %}
    <div data-alert class="alert-box alert radius">
      {{ craft.session.getFlash('error') }}
      <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

This is because flash messages are generally designed to be accessed or displayed only once, on the subsequent request.